Landau-Lifshitz pseudotensor & gravitational conservation
I have recently learned about the Landau–Lifshitz pseudotensor and its statement that gravitational energy-momentum is conserved.
However, from a few searches I found that spacetime curvature is not conserved while energy-momentum of gravity is??
How do we reconcile this idea and connect the 2 ideas that spacetime is energy-momentum conserved but spacetime curvature is not? I thought that the more energy-momentum you have, the greater the curvature is and thereby you should also have the curvature to be conserved?
This seems to be nuanced and I would like to understand it.
Also, can any analogies be made between these ideas in GR and other fields in physics?

You say: "I thought that the more energy-momentum you have, the greater the curvature is"
This is only true when "energy-momentum" refers to non-gravitational energy-momentum.  Gravitational energy-momentum, in the sense of Landau and Lifshitz, is then just defined to be whatever energy-momentum needs to be added to the non-gravitational energy-momentum in order to make the total energy-momentum be conserved.
Therefore, it's also incorrect to say that gravitational energy-momentum is always conserved.  It's only conserved in situations where there is no non-gravitational energy-momentum.

Could you express some of these ideas in mathematical form? I would like to see the non-gravitational energy-momentum and gravitational energy-momentum and how they relate to the Landau and Lifshitz and curvature.

Tachyon: in the Wikipedia link you gave, the part of the equation that contains G_mu_nu is the non-gravitational energy-momentum, and is the part responsible for curvature, and the rest of the equation is the gravitational energy-momentum.  You can see how G_mu_nu is related to curvature here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations
